# Blue box missing when OP answers own question

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, user-card

Usually when the OP of the question answers his/her question there would be a blue box around the user's info.

On the new mobile sites, however, there is no such blue box indicating that the OP answered his/her own question in the user info. The blue box appears for comments and questions, though.

Can we have the blue box for answers?

Example:

[example http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/923558236.png](http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/923558236.png)

This guy is the OP, original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584357/why-applescript-always-send-keystrokes-with-command-down/6584490#6584490)

Comment: @jcolebrand: edited to include screenshot

Comment: home + power = screenshot, that would've been easier you know...

Comment: @jcolebrand: I only had my Mac at that time, so I used the iOS Simulator (and I know how to use the home+power shortcut)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this will go out with the next build.